# Tweaking clang-format for C++20 ranges pipelines

Tags: c++, c++20, clang-format, std-ranges

C++20 (and 23 with `std::ranges::to<T>()`) makes idiomatic the use of `operator|` to make a pipeline of transformations such as this:

```
    return numbers 
        | std::views::filter([](int n) { return n % 2 == 0; })
        | std::views::transform([](int n) { return n * 2; })
        | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
```

With my project's current `.clang-format`, that looks something like

```
    return numbers | std::views::filter([](int n) { return n % 2 == 0; }) |
           std::views::transform([](int n) { return n * 2; }) | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
```

which I find pretty hard to read. If I set `BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: All` I get

```
    return numbers | std::views::filter([](int n) { return n % 2 == 0; })
           | std::views::transform([](int n) { return n * 2; }) | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
```

which is better, but I'd really like the original version with one pipeline operation on each line.

I can adjust the column limit, but that is a major change and also starts to line-break my lambdas, which I don't like:

```
    return numbers | std::views::filter([](int n) {
               return n % 2 == 0;
           })
           | std::views::transform(
               [](int n) { return n * 2; })
           | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
```

I can manually use empty comments to force a newline:

```
    return numbers                                                //
           | std::views::filter([](int n) { return n % 2 == 0; }) //
           | std::views::transform([](int n) { return n * 2; })   //
           | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
```

but again, not ideal knowing that pipelines will be pretty common. Am I missing settings? Or is this more of a feature request I should direct to `clang-format`, like "Add an option so when more than n `operator|` appears in an expression, put each subexpression on its own line."

Comment: This to me is just yet another in an endless series of examples of: formatting usually doesn't matter, but when it does, clang-format does it wrong.

Comment: I've generally been pleased with it, but there are context-dependent things I wish I could control... like this, or like c'tors for 4x4 matrices taking 16 arguments: I wish it could line-break them with aligned commas.

Comment: Since my above comment, I've gotten in the habit of using empty comments (`//`) to force line breaks for things like 4x4 matrices. The commas aren't aligned, but it's a practical solution.

Answer (score 2):

There's a feature request for [`AllowBreakingBinaryOperators`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/58014). Before the feature completes, only compromise can be made.

1. As you've said, use `//` comments to force line breaks.
2. use `clang-format off/on` to disable clang-format and format it yourself.

Here's a more complex solution which combines both:

```cpp
void function() {
  return numbers | std::views::filter([](int n) { return n % 2 == 0; })
         | std::views::transform([](int n) { return n * 2; })
         | std::views::take(3) | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
}
```

First, use `//` to split and then clang-format the code.

```cpp
void function() {
  return numbers
         //
         | std::views::filter([](int n) { return n % 2 == 0; })
         | std::views::transform([](int n) { return n * 2; })
         | std::views::take(3)
         //
         | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
}
```

Next, remove `//`, use `clang-format off/on` to disable clang-format.

```
void function() {
  // clang-format off
  return numbers
         | std::views::filter([](int n) { return n % 2 == 0; })
         | std::views::transform([](int n) { return n * 2; })
         | std::views::take(3)
         | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
  // clang-format on
}
```

As for matrix, the option [`AlignArrayOfStructures`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#alignarrayofstructures) might help.